# passing variable to grep inside lookbehind group

Tags: bash, variables, grep

i am trying to grep for an integer inside some text using a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
var=string2    
cat file.txt | grep -oP '(?<=string1)(\d.*)(<=$var)'
```

but the script outputs nothing.
if i put "string2" instead of "$var" i do get the expected result.
i guess i should escape the variable in some way, but i cant figure out how.
i tried double quotes, curly brackets, escaped double quotes, but nothing works.
i also searched stackoverflow man grep and google.
so what's the proper way to do that?
thanks

Comment: Have you tried \$ ? Actually, now I say that - why do you want to escape it, if your intention is for it to work the same as putting string2 in there? Try replacing the single quotes with double quotes and $var will turn into string2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables are only expanded inside double quotes, not single quotes. So it should be:

```
cat file.txt | grep -oP "(?<=string1)(\d.*)(<=$var)"
```

Answer (score 1):

wrong quotes:

```
$ echo '(?<=string1)(\d.*)(<=$var)'  
(?<=string1)(\d.*)(<=$var)
```

while:

```
$ echo "(?<=string1)(\d.*)(<=$var)"
(?<=string1)(\d.*)(<=string2)
```

`echo` shows what `grep` will see.